# Add generic type in function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the next code:

```
interface Interface<T> {
    submit: T,
    children: (ctx: { test: string, info: string }) => React.ReactNode | ReactElement;
}


const Test: React.FC<Interface<T>> = ({submit, children}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            {children({test: '123', info: '3'})}
        </div>
    )
}
```

How to add `T` here `<Interface<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.FC` can't be used to define a generic component. Fortunately, you don't really need `React.FC`, you can just make the function generic ands specify the type of the props on the parameter:

```
const Test = <T,>({submit, children}: Interface<T>) => {

    return (
        <div>
            {children({test: '123', info: '3'})}
        </div>
    )
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQLABQ9wAdjFlAXlnAJItse4sAHgAqAPjgBvenFlxUAVwBGIYDABccEQBoZc3AAtgAGwAmlJpoAU+AB6bJcVqg3yYUZgHNtcZgQiaLh5MnnAAvgCUcAC8Eth4MAB08fgAchCmWADc9GH0+XS4EEwuWlil0XCi2mJWkooqaj6GJuZYTGGavKzsnKJiUbFSBXJwlDAKUExwVnqjskKmwABuYnPzo5ItZhZ1zq5kAIwATADMZD5+AeTnkXl0GwsA9Eur6xG5QA)

Comment: could you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74474194/using-typescript-generics-in-reactjs-function-components